# Pesquisar dados do GridView Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Tenho um `GridView` chamado `grvListaFuncionario` que é preenchido por dados do meu banco. Estou enfrentando um problema na hora de pesquisar os dados nele.

```
private void Pesquisar()
{

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table = grvListaFuncionarios.DataSource as DataTable;

    table.DefaultView.RowFilter = " nome like '%" + txtPesquisar.Text + "%'" +
                                       "or cargo like '%" + txtPesquisar.Text + "%'" +
                                       "or salário like '%" + txtPesquisar.Text + "%'";

    grvListaFuncionarios.DataSource = table;
    grvListaFuncionarios.DataBind();
}
```

O seguinte erro é retornado:

> Additional information: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

Comment: Agora que vi os erros de português, desculpa.

Comment: `table` está nulo.

Comment: Como faço para minha table deixar de ser nula.

Comment: Verifique a conversão. `grvListaFuncionarios.DataSource as DataTable` vai retornar `null` se **`grvListaFuncionarios.DataSource`** não puder ser convertido para `DataTable`.

Comment: DataTable table = ((DataTable)grvListaFuncionarios.DataSource);
Desse modo da um erro dizendo que eu nao posso realizar essa conversão.

Comment: <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nome">

                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNome" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Nome") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblNome" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Nome") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>

              </asp:TemplateField>

Eu preencho meu gridView desse modo. O erro pode ser por causa disso